# UIViewController still in memory after calling dismiss

Tags: ios, swift

So I create a UICollectionViewController class along with a custom UICollectionViewCell. I am presenting a new UIViewController from the CollectionView and then dismissing it in the UIViewController in order to return to the CollectionView. Everything works except for the fact that after dismissing the UIViewController it still remains in memory which is not what I want. I would like to completely destroy the UIViewController once it is dismiss but cannot figure out how do it.

Am I doing anything wrong? Is it normal for the dismiss ViewController to remain in memory after it's dismissal?

```
// UICollectionViewController class
class MyCollection: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout { 

  let cellId = "cellId"

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    collectionView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
  }

  let viewControllers:[UIViewController] = [ViewController1()]

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return viewControllers.count
  }   

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let activityCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    return activityCell
  }    

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let vc = viewControllers[indexPath.item]

    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 90)
  }    
}

// Custom UICollectionViewCell class
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    backgroundColor = .red
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}

class ViewController1: UIViewController {

  lazy var dismissButton: UIButton = {
    let newButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    newButton.setTitle("Dismiss", for: .normal)
    newButton.backgroundColor = .red
    newButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismissView), for: .touchUpInside)
    newButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return newButton
 }()   

 @objc func dismissView() {
   dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
 }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(dismissButton)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      dissmissButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
      dissmissButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
      ])
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would it destroy? You're holding the reference to each controller inside MyCollection's viewControllers array.

Comment: @PGDev What threw me off was the change in memory before and after presenting the ViewController, didn't understand why the memory size would increase after presenting and remain that size after dismissing but I think I get it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Reason why `ViewController1` instance is not destroyed completely?**

Even after the `viewController` is dismissed, you're still holding the reference to it inside `MyCollection's` `viewControllers` `array`.

**Solution:**

In case, you want a brand new instance of the `controller` everytime a `cell` is tapped, there is no need to store the `controller` in `viewControllers` `array`.

Simply update `didSelectItemAt` method to,

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = ViewController1() //here......
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No you are not doing it wrong. There is no strong retain cycle within your code.

The only problem is, even after you dismiss your view controller, it still resides in here

```
let viewControllers:[UIViewController] = [ViewController1()]
```

If you want the instance to be destroyed completely you need to remove it from the array as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good choice to make a global variable of a viewController.Once you still hold it,you'll be unable to destroy it.Do it like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let vc:UIViewController?

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            vc = ViewController1()
        case 1:
            vc = ViewController2()
        default:
            vc = ViewController0()
        }
        present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

And if there are many viewControllers, maybe it will be better to create a Array of Class like this:

```
guard let nameSpace = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String else { return }
let clsName = String(format: "%@.%@", nameSpace, cList[indexPath.row])
let cls = (NSClassFromString(clsName) as? UIViewController.Type)!
let vc = cls.init()

present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

clist:`let cList = ["FirstController","SecondController"]`

PS:
Of course I would not use this route if I get 50 ViewControllers.I just think that we can just use the most convenient way to solve the problem.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: If you had lets say 50 ViewControllers would you still go this route? Either way gave you an upvote because you showed me another way to deal with multiple ViewControllers.